# Getting words out of a numpy array of sentence strings

Tags: python, string, numpy, nltk, tokenize

I have a numpy array of sentences (strings)

```
arr = np.array(['It's the most wonderful time of the year.',
               'With the kids jingle belling.',
               'And everyone telling you be of good cheer.',
               'It's the hap-happiest season of all.'])
```

(that I read from a csv file). I need to make a numpy array with all the unique words in these sentences.

So what I need is

```
array(["It's", "the", "most", "wonderful", "time", "of" "year", "With", "the", "kids", "jingle", "belling" "and", "everyone", "telling", "you", "be", "good", "cheer", "It's", "hap-happiest", "season", "all"])
```

I could do this like

```
o = []
for x in arr:
    o += x.split()
words = np.array(o)
unique_words = np.array(list(set(words.tolist())))
```

but as this involves first making lists and then converting *that* to numpy array, it's obviously gonna be slow and inefficient for large data.

I also tried nltk as in

```
words = np.array([])
for x in arr:
    words = np.append(words, nltk.word_tokenize(x))
```

but with this too seems inefficient as a new array is created on each iteration instead of the old one being modified.

I suppose there's some elegant way of achieving what I want using more of numpy.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Read the csv file into a list and make the list a set?

Comment: How do you read those sentences from `csv` file? How they are preserved in that file?

Comment: @Kasramvd I read with `df=pd.read_csv()` of pandas and then used to `df.values` to get the `arr`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try something like this:

```
vocab = set()
for x in arr:
    vocab.update(nltk.word_tokenize(x))
```

`set.update()` takes an iterable to add elements to existing set.

**Update**:

Also, you can look at the working of [CountVectorizer in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) which:

> converts a collection of text documents to a matrix of token counts.

And it uses a dictionary to keep track of the unique words:

```
    # raw_documents is an iterable of sentences.
    for doc in raw_documents:
        feature_counter = {}

        # analyze will split the sentences into tokens 
        # and apply some preprocessing on them (like stemming, lemma etc)
        for feature in analyze(doc):
            try:
                # vocabulary is a dictionary containing the words and their counts
                feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]
                ...
                ...
```

And I think it works pretty efficiently. So I think you can also use a `dict()`  instead of set. I am not familiar with working of NLTK, but I think that must also contain something equivalent to CountVectorizer.

Comment: @J...S I have added some more info to answer. Please check that

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure numpy is the best way to go here. You can achieve what you want with nested lists and sets or dictionaries.

One useful thing to know is that the tokenizer methods from nltk can process a list of sentences, and will return a list of tokenized sentences. For example:

```
from nltk.tokenize import WordPunktTokenizer
wpt = WordPunktTokenizer()

tokenized = wpt.tokenize_sents(arr)
```

This will return a list of lists of the tokenized sentences in `arr`, i.e.:

```
[['It', "'", 's', 'the', 'most', 'wonderful', 'time', 'of', 'the', 'year', '.'],
 ['With', 'the', 'kids', 'jingle', 'belling', '.'],
 ['And', 'everyone', 'telling', 'you', 'be', 'of', 'good', 'cheer', '.'],
 ['It', "'", 's', 'the', 'hap', '-', 'happiest', 'season', 'of', 'all', '.']]
```

nltk comes with lots of different tokenizers, and so will give you options for how best to split the sentences into word tokens. You can then use something like the following to get the unique set of words / tokens:

```
unique_words = set()
for toks in tokenized:
    unique_words.update(toks)
```